# Powershell Access Denied Issue

Tags: windows, powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to download registry hives from computers in my domain, and I'm testing some commands locally first. I have two machines (VMs) not on the same domain: SRV2K12 and US-TEST. I can run `reg.exe save HKLM\SYSTEM \\SRV2K12\Hives\<hostname>` (where  is the local hostname manually typed) successfully on both machines. However, I ultimately need to run the commands remotely, so I'm using Invoke-Command. On my Win 2012 server, I can use `Invoke-Command -computername SRV2K12 -ScriptBlock {reg.exe save HKLM\SYSTEM \\SRV2K12\Hives\<hostname>` and it works as expected. On my Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines, it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
ERROR: Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo           : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Access id denied.: String) []. RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId  : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName         : <hostname>
NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
```

I can run `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {reg.exe save HKLM\SYSTEM \\SRV2K12\Hives\US-TEST}` on the US-TEST Windows 7 machine just fine, and it saves the hive to the remote computer. But when I add the `-computername US-TEST` attribute (on the Win 7 or 10 machine) it tells me access is denied.

Any ideas how I can get that to work? I have already ran `enabled-psremoting -force` on those machines and it completes successfully. I also ran `Set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *` on both machines. No change.

Comment: Sounds like the two-hop problem. If you really need it, the easy but insecure answer is to use CredSSP.

Answer (score 0):

2-Hop remoting is your problem, as BenH said CredSSP can resolve it but so can a small design change on your part, rather than trying to do the save from the remote host just return the data to your calling computer and do the save from there.  Below is one way to do it, but you can get even more efficient and avoid the temp file if you use get-itemproperty instead of reg.exe  Also please note that there is a good chance that this will not work when you use invoke-command with the -computername parameter targeting the computer you are running from, -computername needs to be called against a remote machine.

```
$SB = {
  reg.exe save HKLM\SYSTEM "$($env:TMP)\reg"
  $tempFile = gc "$($env:TMP)\reg"
  return $tempFile
}

$result = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB -computername COMPUTERNAME
$result | Out-File \\SRV2K12\Hives\US-TEST
```

Comment: why work around, when you can easily configure credssp? https://4sysops.com/archives/using-credssp-for-second-hop-powershell-remoting/

Comment: Because CredSSP imposes additional security risks and this method does not.  you can mimikatz a password out of a remote session on a CredSSP enabled machine but can't do so when using normal authentication.  There's a reason MS doesn't default to CredSSP.

Comment: Honestly didn't mean that to be anything other than informative, apologie's if I came across in any other way

Comment: Mike, without the -computername command, how can I target the US-TEST machine if I'm running the script from a different machine. Ultimately, I need to run this script against hundreds of hostnames to pull down my list of registry hives.

Comment: apologies, that switch should have been present in my example.  you only need to omit it when you are targeting the computer you are running the script from (so if you are running from US-TEST you cant also pass -computername US-TEST).  you *could* also use Get-ItemProperty and avoid all of this invoke-command stuff but that's a whole other solution.

Comment: And I won't be able to use CredSSP. Too insecure. I only ran `Set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *` on my test systems to see if I can prove that WOULD be a solution.

Comment: yea I'd go with the method listed then, or the powershell native get-itemproperty, or just save the file and then reach out and pick it up off the admin share

Comment: I just tried running the code above to pull the hive from the local system and that didn't work. I had to exit the script with CTRL+C and no output was produced. I typed literally character-for-character what you wrote above, so my apologies if something there should have changed.

Comment: I looked into the get-itemproperty command, but I can't figure out how to configure the output. I tried: `get-itemproperty HKLM:\SYSTEM | Out-File \\SRV2K12\Hives\SRV2K12` but that only output a 1kb file. I'm looking into whether or not I have to enter different attributes to pull down the entire SYSTEM hive.

Comment: so I did some tests and I was able to get my code to run against a single system (won't be able to test remote until 2moro when I'm back at work) however I ran into a bunch of problems using reg while within ISE while on Windows 10 so make sure you test from the console.  Also, I forgot that get-itemproperty doesn't recurse and it won't be able to give you an importable file the way that reg can, but since your backing up all of system I assume that's not what you need the files for, if you can you give me a bit more info about what data you need and I can help with grabbing it